# backbone.js events not bind to fire action on text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, cordova, backbone-events

I have a text area in my template .i want to pass text value from text area to function (view ) change event. I bound the "change" event to `textarea` but action is not working.

template

```
<div id="replyt" class="commentArea">                                           <textarea id="rep" class="form-control" placeholder="What's on your mind ?" rows="2"></textarea>
    </div>
```

My view

```
var PostwallView = Backbone.View.extend({

 el: $("#content"),
     events: {

      'change #rep': 'test',// or which event i need

             },
```

My action

```
 test:function(e)
      {
      var val = $(e.currentTarget).val();
       alert( val );
    e.preventDefault();

     },
```

Here I used `keyup` and `keydown`. My event is working but action fire in first character when I am typing in text area

Answer (score 1):

The `input` and `keydown/up` events are triggered when the value changes or a key is pressed. I don't know when you expect `change` to trigger, but `blur` triggers when the textarea loses focus:

```
'blur #rep': 'test'
```

Comment: but when i am click in empty text box action is fire

Comment: in page any where i tabbed its fire action @jgillich

Answer (score 0):

```
"blur #rep":"yourMethod"


 yourMethod:function(){
 if($('#textArea').val() != null || '#textArea').val() != undefined){
  /*Call your other function here*/
}
}
```